# Determine the data types

Tags: java, types, identifier, primitive-types

I'm very new to programming and still getting confused with some things.  Below is a class exercise.

We have to use the context in the below code to determine the data type of the identifiers in the code.

```
if (a.length( ) > 10)

{

     b = ! ( c < 4 );

     z = ugly ( a, b, c – 9 );

}

if ( z.equals( “I think I got it” ) )

{

     System.out.println ( “Yea” );

}
```

Here were my answers:
  a;  is int

b;  is int

c;  is int

z;  is String

I'm sure I got a few wrong.  I guess I get confused when I see 'a' & 'z' in multiple places.  Again, I'm just trying to get a better understanding at identifying them.

Comment: int is a primitive type and does not have `length()` function. so your answer is wrong. the key to answer the question is `length()` and `equals()` functions for a and z. for b and c, check the values. you will find the answer then! ;)

Comment: `a` must have type `org.omg.CORBA.TypeCode`, because that class has a `length()` method.  Or it could be `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceArray`, or `java.lang.StringBuffer`, or one of 26 others in the JRE that have `length()` methods.  Really, if this is a class exercise, it's one of the stupider ones I've run across.  Even if you limit yourself to the primitive types and `String`, you still don't know what `c` is.  (P.S. Matthew, please don't quote anything I've said in your homework.  I'm being very sarcastic here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.length()
```

length() is a method of the String object;

```
c < 4
```

This is boolean test (result can be true or false) where c can be number (int).

```
z.equals( “I think I got it” )
```

equals is a method of Object, but it checks z value in this case with String.

So
a is String

b is boolean

c is int or other numeric (maybe long or byte, short)

z is String or otehr non-primitive Object

Answer (score 1):

`a` cannot be an `int` because you cannot call methods like `.length()` on an `int`.

`b` cannot be an `int` because in the line `b = ! ( c < 4 );`, the expression on the right side is of type `boolean` and you cannot assign a `boolean` to an `int`.

`c` might indeed be an `int`, but it could also be a `long`.

`z` might indeed be a `String`, but it could in principle be any non-primitive type (because all objects have an `equals()` method).

Comment: I would say Z is an object, because Strings are objects in Java anyways. Practically, it's almost definitely a string because the equals method of an object defaults to comparing memory location (as you can see, the example compares it to a string... this would only happen if someone overwrote the object's equal function)